# Random crashes in mshtml.dll

Tags: winapi, internet-explorer, clipboard, webview2

Recently we are getting random crashes, which are rather hard to reproduce. There's no common action being done in our app, sometimes they just happen when you leave the app idling for a longer while. They have one thing in common though: The top of the stacktrace is always in `mshtml!CDoc` and looks like this:

```
[0x0]   mshtml!CDoc::ReadOptionSettingsFromRegistry + 0xed   
[0x1]   mshtml!CDoc::UpdateFromRegistry + 0x123   
[0x2]   mshtml!CDoc::OnSettingsChange + 0xd0   
[0x3]   mshtml!OnSettingsChangeAllDocs + 0x8f   
[0x4]   mshtml!GlobalWndProc_SEH + 0x13b   
[0x5]   mshtml!GlobalWndProc + 0x2d   
[0x6]   user32!_InternalCallWinProc + 0x2b   
[0x7]   user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow + 0x33a   
[0x8]   user32!DispatchClientMessage + 0xea   
[0x9]   user32!__fnINSTRINGNULL + 0x40   
[0xa]   ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher + 0x4d   
[0xb]   user32!GetMessageW + 0x2e
```

The crashes are caused by access violations (c0000005, invalid pointer read) in `mshtml!CDoc::ReadOptionSettingsFromRegistry`.

There's no particular Windows message being processed at that time, it might be anything. The message loop is just a regular

```
MSG msg;
while (::GetMessage(&msg, 0 ,0, 0)) { ... }
```

I couldn't find any documentation for those CDoc functions. Does anyone have any idea what might cause these crashes or how to tackle this problem?

Two hints: 1) It might have something to do with copying/pasting HTML with the system clipboard. 2) We have both hosted IE browsers (legacy) and WebView2 browsers (already converted from IE) in our app. Perhaps they interfere with each other?

Comment: It might be created by IE11 addons. You should disable them all during your tests see if it's related. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-add-ons-in-internet-explorer-11-0a490ccc-83ab-0723-f9cd-2ebad8fa114e

Comment: Try running the application under [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/application-verifier) to get closer to the root cause. Alternatively consider pulling a [Time Travel Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) trace from the application. When it crashes, the trace has all information you need to identify the issue.

Comment: @SimonMourier Oh my, there's a whole bunch of addons I had no idea about... But since this crash is so hard to reproduce, disabling them and not crashing wouldn't prove anything.

Comment: @IInspectable Normally our app requires about 200..300 MB of memory during startup, then goes down again to about 150 MB. With Application Verifier, memory goes up to 1.9 GB right away. Then when I do the tiniest operation which requires any additional memory, it will throw bad alloc exceptions. App verifier still uncovered a few nooby mistakes during startup/shutdown, but I can't get to the point where it crashes. Similar situation with time travel debugging, 1.9 GB memory, mshtml.dll can't even be loaded. I guess I'm out of luck with these two.

Comment: I guess this is a 32-bit application then, meaning that 1.9GB is nearing available address space. If you cannot recompile for a 64-bit target, you could try enabling the [`/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses) linker option. That at least gets you to 4GB of address space for a 32-bit application when executing on a 64-bit host OS. I don't know whether this works if any of your dependencies aren't `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`. Still worth a shot, if you manage to get the build running before lunch break.

Comment: Yes, it's a 32-bit application and we already use `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`. I just double-checked with SysInternals Process Explorer and the virtual size actually goes up to over 4 GB. It's the private bytes / working set which peak at 1.9 GB.

Comment: "disabling them and not crashing wouldn't prove anything", maybe although it still would be interesting but disabling them and still crashing would definitely prove something. If you can't reproduce, you've got a bigger problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved!

I was finally able to reproduce the crash sometimes on a VM with a debugger installed. Digging into the disassembly, I found out that `mshtml!GlobalWndProc` tried to handle `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` every time it crashed (as indicated by the `OnSettingsChange...` functions in the call stack). This in turn enabled me to reproduce the crash consistently by first pasting anything from the clipboard into one of our HTML editors and then by either broadcasting this message myself or by changing any system setting (like selecting a different system sound scheme). Narrowing it further down from there, it turned out that the culprit was a missing virtual destructor in a clipboard handler class. This left an `mshtml::IHTMLDocument2Ptr` unreleased, which somehow lead to the crash in MSHTML later while handling that Windows message.

In summary, the crash was caused by an unreleased smart pointer in our code, but was triggered by random system settings changes (probably scheduled by IT departments).